# Cairo PDF not converting unicode while creating

Tags: python, svg, cairo, pdf-conversion

I am converting SVG to PDF using Cairo PDF library of Python. It is working well for ASCII characters, but for Unicode chars it is displaying a square box. Is there any solution to deal with this problem?

```
cairosvg.svg2pdf(
    url='svg_file_with_unicode_character.svg',
    write_to='output.expecting_unicode_character.pdf',
    output_height=720,
    output_width=1200
    )
```

Comment: Presumably the font you're using doesn't have glyphs for those characters. Switch to one that does.

Comment: @RobertLongson Thanks for your time sir, can you elaborate how we can include all those character and how we can find proper font font for that, and  is that to be included in SVG itself or we can do that from Cairo, can you give good explanation? It will help me.

Comment: add font-family="some font that has the glyphs you need" to the SVG file you're converting.

Comment: Thanks @RobertLongson,  I added font called GNU Unifont, now it works. Great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got a solution for this. I included a font called [GNU Unifont](http://www.unifoundry.com/unifont/index.html) in SVG as following:

```
.font-class{
      font-family: Unifont 
}
```

Which seems to have all the required glyphs for Unicode chars that I need.

Kudos to GNU Unifont! from hint "add font-family" by @RobertLongson

Answer (score 0):

In my SVG I have to add the following font-family and now I am able to convert svg to png

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="100" height="100">
   <text x="20" y="20" font-family="Segoe UI Symbol">&#x2643;</text>
</svg>
```